# HighStocks - Adding 2 charts on same page

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using HighStocks.js, I tried to add 2 identical graph on the same html page.

My code look like this:

```
function createGraph(placeHolderId, uniqueName, series) {
    $(placeHolderId).highcharts(uniqueName, {
            rangeSelector : { selected : 1 },
            series : series
    });
}
```

And I call it 2 times:

```
createGraph('#marketdata', 'StockChart', series1);
createGraph('#returns', 'Returns', series1);
```

Even if series are the same, 'market data' get created then for the second I get the error:

```
TypeError: Highcharts[constr] is not a constructor
chart = new Highcharts[constr](options, args[1]);
```

on line 1041 of highstock.src.js.

Why is the second failing ?

Comment: Does it do the same if you only do the `returns` chart without the `marketdata` one?

Comment: Thanks cookie monster, your question brings the light! It wasn't working on the other way around. In fact, uniqueName needs to be 'StockChart' which seems to be the type of the chart.

Comment: Becasue you place "returns" inside highchas and you achieve something like: (placeHolderId).highcharts('returns',options) which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the name of the chart needs to be 'StockChart' which is the type of the chart and not a variable name.

```
$(placeHolderId).highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : { selected : 1 },
        series : series
});
```